# Mixed last/first and first/last names in reference list

Tags: biblatex

I got a comment by an anonymous reviewer about my reference list in a conference paper. Essentially, I have mixed order between first and last names in the references.

To understand the problem, run the following example with lualatex and biber. The reference list shows "Pepper, Peter and Petra Hofstedt".

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{pepper2006fp,
     author = {Pepper, Peter and Hofstedt, Petra},
      title = {Funktionale Programmierung -- Sprachdesign und Programmiertechnik},
       year = {2006},
  publisher = {Springer}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a citation \parencite{pepper2006fp}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Biber is a suggested tool for the references and explicitly supported by the conference template, so I assume the problem lies in my usage of lualatex. Or is the reviewer mistaken and this is actually the expected behavior?

Comment: Try it without lualatex (this file should work fine). I strongly suspect that the TeX engine is irrelevant. So there's probably a way to make biber format all names the way you want.

Comment: The reviewer *may* be mistaken also, because this varies from style to style. Chicago is consistently Given Family, APA is Family, Given; and MLA is Given Family for the first author and Family Given for others. Better check with the editor.

Comment: i have nothing against having the names of second and further authors in "natural" order, but my comma sense tells me that if the first author is listed "last, first", then there should be a comma after the "first".  (this is *not* the same as an "oxford comma".)  what really matters is, can the reader immediately understand exactly who the authors are and locate the source in a library or online?  if comprehension fails by that criterion, then the rules are misguided.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with LuaLaTeX. It depends on the settings of `authoryear`.

`authoryear` uses the definition

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
```

whereby `sortname` is defined as (`biblatex.def`)

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}
```

So you have to changed according to your needs `sortname`:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

or

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
```

**Result with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}`**

[image]

**Result with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`**
[image]

## Complete example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{pepper2006fp,
     author = {Pepper, Peter and Hofstedt, Petra},
      title = {Funktionale Programmierung -- Sprachdesign und Programmiertechnik},
       year = {2006},
  publisher = {Springer}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a citation \parencite{pepper2006fp}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```