# Biblatex: incorrect name order for mutiple authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, biber

I would like to cite the following

```
@article{ott2015,
    author =       "Ott, Dennis and de Vries, Mark",
    title =        "Right Dislocation as Deletion",
    journal =      "Natural Language and Linguistic Theory",
    volume =       "34",
    number =       "2",
    pages =        "641-690",
    year =         "2015",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11049-015-9307.7",
    keywords =     "ott15"
}
```

I use `biber`. But citing `\cite{ott2015}` gives me this:

> Ott and de Vries 2015
>
> References
>
> Ott, Dennis and Mark de Vries (2015). “Right Dislocation as Deletion”. In: Natural Language and Linguistic Theory 34.2, pp. 641–690. doi: http://dx.doi. org/10.1007/s11049-015-9307.7.

Any author whose name is not the first is sorted as "Firstname Lastname" instead of "Lastname, Firstname", even though LaTeX clearly recognizes which one is the last name and which one is the first name. Help?

Comment: Does `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` work for you? See [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/105447) for more details.

Comment: This isn't "incorrect", it's just not what you want. It's a very common style in author/year citation schemes.

Comment: This is more specific to the point in question [Mixed last/first and first/last names in reference list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361486/105447).

Comment: @AlanMunn, I agree that this is very likely a duplicate (should we wait to hear from the OP?). But I think this last one I mentioned is a better one, for it is not specific to the verbose style which has further requirements not needed in this case.

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, that's a better duplicate for sure. (Although technically the OP hasn't actually shown how they're generating the bibliography...). You can add your close vote and suggest that as the duplicate.