# Change style of citing a book with multiple authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to use a given bibliography style for my work in biblatex. Everything is fine when the book has only one author, when it's got two I get this:

```
Novotny, Ivan and Michal Hruska (1998). Biologie cloveka pro gymnazia. Fortuna, Praha. ISBN: 8071684627.
```

which isn't the format I need. Following my given format, it would be:

```
Novotny, Ivan and Hruska, Michal (1998). Biologie cloveka pro gymnazia. Fortuna, Praha. ISBN: 8071684627.
```

or

```
Novotny, Ivan; Hruska, Michal (1998). Biologie cloveka pro gymnazia. Fortuna, Praha. ISBN: 8071684627.
```

How can the correct format be achieved?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361486/35864. `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` should give you what you want. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share a minimum working example for your case, so I don't know for sure what can be edited in your latex code to produce the exact thing you are looking for. I suggest:

```
@article{Novotny:1998,
  author         = "Novotny, Ivan and Hruska, Michal",
  title          = "{Biologie cloveka pro gymnazia}",
  journal        = "Fortuna, Praha",
  volume         = "ISBN: 8071684627",
  year           = "1998",
```

}

Include this in your example.bib file and include that in your text.tex file as \bibliography{example}. This should give you: [image: Output]

Also check: [Bibtex at Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles)

Comment: Just so you notice, out of three formats you have given, the first and second are exactly the same, so it is even harder to find out what it is that you don't want. In the answer I have given, you can edit it to suit you as you want. @Xxx_Ddd

Comment: thanks for your response, I think I found out how to resolve it with your help. The difference between the first and second formats is simple, the first is `surname1, name1 and name2 surname2`, when the second is `surname1, name1 and surname2, name2`.

Comment: If my answer is suitable, can you accept it as a solution here? @XxxDdd